# How to change the title of the UINavigationBar back button to "Back"

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

When I push a view onto the navigation controller the back button's title get's set to the title of the previous view. How can I get the back button to just say "Back"?

Comment: Worth mentioning that the iOS Human Interface Guidelines specify that the back button "should be labeled with the previous level's title" in order to help orientate your Users: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH12-SW3

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Write this code in your `viewwillappear`:

```
UIBarButtonItem *_backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = _backButton;
[_backButton release];
_backButton = nil;
```

Comment: This will neither look or act like a back button.

Comment: Yes it will. The `backBarButtonItem` property is specifically designed to work like this and will take the title or custom view from the `UIBarButtonItem` you give to it and make it into a back-style button.

Comment: Just wanted to say, as the asker of this question this solution definitely worked for me. I just needed to add the code to the viewWillAppear of the view controller that is PUSHING the new view.

Comment: @MikeWeller - you're right, thanks for the correction. I misread the answer as setting the leftBarButtonItem.  I was just coming back to make the point that cgossain has made in comments - it has to be on the previous view controller, not the one being presented, which is a common misconception.

Answer (score 3):

In the previous view controller, have it set its title in `viewWillAppear`, and then in the code that pushes the new view controller, have it change its title to 'Back.'

Example:

```
-(void)showNextScreen{
     [self setTitle:@"Back"]; 
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:asdf animated:YES];
}
-(void)viewWillAppear{
     [super viewWillAppear];
     [self setTitle:@"My Actual Title"];
}
```

Comment: Sounded good..but when the new screen comes up, the past screen looks Back in the title, which isn't preferable. Nice idea though!

Comment: If you're reading this answer -> use the accepted answer instead, it's much better!