# Custom back button on navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

In my application there are many `UIViewControllers` with `UINavigationControllers`. There must be a "back" button and a "home" `UIButton` on the `UINavigationBar`. All of this works fine.

But some of my `UIViewControllers` have long names, and sometimes there is too small place left for it. I'm trying to replace the original label of the "back" button (it shows the title of the previous view) with a custom "Back", but whatever I tried it didn't work:

```
// Title didn't change
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Back"];

// Action didn't set, no response from button ( button didn't do anything )
[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem
   setAction:self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.action];
```

And I need the "back" button to have a style like in this question: *[Draw custom Back button on iPhone Navigation Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260238/draw-custom-back-button-on-iphone-navigation-bar)*

Comment: Is the answer provided in the question you reference not sufficient?

Comment: It sets (=changes) previous view's title

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the title of the UINavigationBar back button to "Back"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046622/how-to-change-the-title-of-the-uinavigationbar-back-button-to-back)

Comment: it is not. that solution didn't saves shape of button

Comment: before iOS 7 there is no official API to do what you want. Not sure about iOS 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
UIBarButtonItem *backBarBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(popViewController)];
[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backBarBtnItem];

- (void)popViewController
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: that didn't work.  I can remove usual back button and add my own, but how to make it's shape like usual's?

Comment: for that you need to add custom button having that shaped image i guess...[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customButton];

Comment: that's a little barbarian's code, but i guess, there is no other solution... So, let us be a barbarian for a while :) Thanks for responce anyway.

Answer (score 50):

Try the following. It will definitely work:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
    [customBarItem release];
}

- (void)back {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Make sure you have an button image with the size of a navigation bar back button in your resource folder with name `back.png`.

Feel free if any other assistance is required.

Comment: I find that you can make the custom back button indistinguishable from the stock iOS back button by also setting an image for the highlighted state, like this: [button setImage:highlightedButtonImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

Comment: why can't I add a title to my custom back button with this code?
`[button setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: Navigation bar has button of type UIBarButton.You can create UIBarButton items with custom content or create standard system items depending on your needs.

Comment: Actually I am using your code above and there is this line `[button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];`
I thought that I could add `[button setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];` right after, and that would work, but it didn't...

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you are not customizing the back button, rather you are adding a "leftBarButtonItem" which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

***Target:***
customizing all back button on UINavigationBar to an white icon

***Steps:***
1. in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method of AppDelete：

UIImage *backBtnIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navBackBtn"];

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
    [UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [UINavigationBar appearance].backIndicatorImage = backBtnIcon;
    [UINavigationBar appearance].backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backBtnIcon;
}else{

    UIImage *backButtonImage = [backBtnIcon resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, backBtnIcon.size.width - 1, 0, 0)];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonImage  forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -backButtonImage.size.height*2) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

2.in the "viewDidLoad" method of the common super ViewController class:

```
 if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
        UIBarButtonItem *backItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                    target:nil
                                                                    action:nil];
        [self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backItem];
    }else{
        //do nothing
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing this all over the place like I am, you're better off implementing Anil's solution as a category:

```
@interface UIViewController (CustomBackButton)

- (void) setCustomBackButton;
- (void) back;

@end

@implementation UIViewController (CustomBackButton)

- (void) setCustomBackButton
{
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
}

- (void) back
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

More simply:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barBtnItem = 
  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Indietro"
                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                 target:self
                                 action:@selector(pop)];
[barBtnItem setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barBtnItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two controllers - Controller1 and Controller2. Controller2 is pushed from Controller1. So before pushing the Controller2 on the navigationController from Controller1

```
Controller2 *controller2 = [[[Controller2 alloc]  init]autorelease];
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Now, in the viewDidLoad: method of Controller2, add the following snippet

```
UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem =[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(goBackToAllPets:)]autorelease];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
```

and in the backButtonClicked method, you can perform the checks you want to.