# Customize title attributes of specific back button

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, customization, uibarbuttonitem

The appearance proxy is useful as long as you don't use any UI elements provided by the OS, such as the `MFMailComposeViewController` class. For this reason, I need to customize the bar button items in the navigation bar, the **back button** in particular.

**What is the problem?** This seems problematic when it comes to modifying the title attributes of the back button. Quite a bit has been written about [customizing the back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221581/custom-back-button-on-navigation-bar), but I can't seem to find information about modifying the title attributes (text color, shadow color, etc.) of the back button (*without using the appearance proxy*).

**What have I tried?** Setting the title attributes of the `backBarButtonItem` property as shown below. It doesn't matter if I do this in the child or parent view controller. This works fine for the `leftBarButtonItem` and `rightBarButtonItem' items, which is what confuses me.

```
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:titleAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Of course, using the appearance proxy works fine as well (see below), but this messes up navigation bars provided by the OS as mentioned above.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:titleAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: The problem is, the `backBarButtonItem` property itself is `nil`! So, passing any message to it will have no effect. As @βhargavḯ points out, this is in coherence with the documentation. So, without using the `appearance` API, you could create a `UIBarButtonItem` instance with the desired customizations in code and set it as the back button instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target the appearance of UIBarButtonItems only when they exists within a certain view hierarchy. So you could create a subclass of UINavigationController, say MyNavigationController and do:

`[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], [MyNavigationController class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:titleAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: This seems to be the easiest approach in combination with the `appearance` API.

Answer (score 1):

*I can't seem to find information about modifying the title attributes (text color, shadow color, etc.) of the back button* - of course you will not find.

As per [UINavigationItem Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html)

> If you want to specify a custom image or title for the back button,
>   you can assign a custom bar button item (with your custom title or
>   image) to this property instead. When configuring your bar button
>   item, do not assign a custom view to it; the navigation item ignores
>   custom views in the back bar button anyway.